# Time delay for Popup in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, popup, timedelay

I am new to windows phone development and I would like to know is there any thing like timedelay in WP7.

As I would like to show Popup after few seconds after image loads completely(say after 5 sec I need to open a popup automatically)without clicking any button.

As of now I am doing this way but it opens Popup as soon as the image loads.

```
 Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    photoChooserTask = New PhotoChooserTask()
    AddHandler photoChooserTask.Completed, AddressOf photoChooserTask_Completed
 End Sub
 Dim photoChooserTask As PhotoChooserTask
```

Add Image:

```
 Private Sub AddImage_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Try
            photoChooserTask.Show()

        Catch ex As System.InvalidOperationException

            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred.")
    End Try
 End Sub
```

Afer Loading Image:

```
 Private Sub photoChooserTask_Completed(sender As Object, e As PhotoResult)

        If e.TaskResult = TaskResult.OK Then
            'Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
            Dim bmp As System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage = New System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage()
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto)
            myImage.Source = bmp
        End If

  Dim popup As New Popup()
        popup.VerticalOffset = 140
        Dim control As New PhonePage3()
        popup.Child = control
        popup.IsOpen = True
    End Sub
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy, use the Timer class for your task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).

Create the timer:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(OnTimerDone);
```

Start the Timer to get a callback in 5 secs (5000 msecs):

```
myTimer.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Define the callback function:

```
private void OnTimerDone(object state)
{
    // your code here
}
```

That's all :-) Sorry for C# code but I think it should be easy to translate it to VB.

Comment: @Torben-It's Ok no problem no need of sorry even if it's in C#,I can manage.Thanks for that actually just now I was trying with background worker :)